# my php login doesn't log to home page from the first time

Tags: php, html

The problem seems to be as follows:
I open the browser.
Point the browser to localhost/myproject/.
login page is loaded on the browser.
I enter the email address and password and click login.
instead of going to the home page the login page reloaded again.
I enter the same email address and password again and click login
this time it goes to the home page correctly??.
and something increase the ambiguity that the problem appears only for the first login. If I logout and login again from the same browser it respond from the first time.
my login code:

```
<?php
                   session_start();
                   if (isset($_SESSION['email']))
                      header("location:" . $config_basedir);


                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
                        $password=  trim($_POST['password']);
                        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

                        $query = "select * from users where email= '" . $email .
                                "' and password= '" . md5($password) . "'";
                        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

                        if ($result != NULL) {
                            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                                }
                                header("location: " . $config_basedir);
                            }

                            echo "<p style='color:red ;font-size:15px'>****invalid login***</p>";
                        } else
                            echo "<p style='color:red ;font-size:15px'>****invalid login****</p>";
                    }
                    ?>
                 <html>
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPTNAME']; ?>">
                        <p><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email address"></p>
                        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

                        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
                    </form> 
                  </html>
```

and at the Home page I use:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
        header("location:" . $config_basedir . "login.php");
  ?>
```

Comment: 1st `$config_basedir` must be declared on the page. 2nd Put exit(); after header e.g. `header("location: " . $config_basedir); exit();`

Comment: thanks alot that was exactly the problem. require('config.php'); must be above header("location:".$config_basedir); since config.php contains the variable $config_basedir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password');
```

and change

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                                }
                                header("location: " . $config_basedir);
                            }
```

to:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
       $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
       header("location: " . $config_basedir);
 }
```

Comment: $_POST['password'] - FTFY

Comment: I'm sorry, my code has two additional lines after  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //they are as follw                                        $email = trim($_POST['email']);                              $password=  trim($_POST['password']);.......

Comment: Then i guess you could try header("Location: <- consider using big L and empty space after : 
Also try redirecting to absolute URLs and try debuging by trying to output Session contents $_SESSION